# Restrict or check for multiple data entries before saving in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How can restrict or checking  data entries before saving?

> Example

So i have different Dogs who are eating Meals with different Sizes (in Gramm) and different Foodtypes (Pork, Beef etc.).

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**models.py**

```
 class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    meal = models.ManyToManyField('Meal')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Meal(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey('Foodtype', null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    min_g = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    max_g = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
            return 'Meal: %s Size: %s g to max. %s g' % (self.food, self.min_g, self.max_g )


class Foodtype(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Every Time i enter a new Dog i also can create a new Meal. For Instance i added **Harry** (Dog.name) who is eating **Beef** (Foodtype.name) of a Size min. 200 (Meal.min_g) gramm to 300 (Meal.min_g) gramm

So in my Meal Table is now a Entry of **Beef, 200, 300**

But Harry the Dog can have multiple Meals so i choose also **Pork, 200, 300**.

If a other user now enters a new Dog who is eating exactly the same, the user could choose the data-point **Beef, 200, 300** but he could also easily end up with a double entry by accident because it is a many-to-many relation (see following picture).

[![Double Entry][2]][2]

On the Other Hand i need this Releation because the Dogs can eat multiple or different meals.

> So my Question is:

How can i restrict the Model to only allow one object constellation of Meal in the table? Or in other Words if there is already a data entry with **Beef, 200, 300** please User use this object and do not create a new object.

> Update

As @bdoubleu and @ ivissani proposed i added `unique_together` and `unique=True`. Now a error Message **Meal with this Food, Min g and Max g already exists.** is displayed, every time a duplicate is entered. That is what i searched for - Thanks!

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    meal = models.ManyToManyField('Meal')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Meal(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey('Foodtype', null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    min_g = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    max_g = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['food', 'min_g', 'max_g']

    def __str__(self):
            return 'Meal: %s Size: %s g to max. %s g' % (self.food, self.min_g, self.max_g )


class Foodtype(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You can override the save method of Dog class and use the get_or_create method to see if entry is already present in the meal table, if yes just link it to the meal relation in Dog table else create a new entry in meal table and then link it. You can do this in a view as well . Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: Add a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) constraint to the meta options on your model. `unique_together = ['food', 'min_g' 'max_g']`

Comment: Besides what @bdoubleu said you should also add a `unique=True` to the `name` field in the `Foodtype` model in order to avoid having duplicate food types.

Comment: @bdoubleu i tried your proposal **(see above Update)**. Unfortunately i can still create duplicates in my Meal Table?

Comment: @ivissani i tried your proposal **(see above Update)**. Unfortunately i can still create duplicates in my Meal Table?

Comment: @black_hole_sun it should be `class Meta:` and you'll need to run migrations after making the change.

Comment: @bdoubleu a detail that i missed. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To do this, use `get_or_create`. This method will do exactly what it says. It will `get` the object from the database if it already exists, or it will `create` it if it doesn't.

Like this:

```
food, created = Food.objects.get_or_create(name='Beef')
meal, created = Meal.objects.get_or_create(food=food, min_g=200, max_g=300)
```

The `created` variable will contain `True` if the object was created, and `False` if it was fetched from the database.

Good luck!